# XSLT Munchen method and child element of prior XML tag

Tags: xslt

I've been attempting to group data to reduce the output, however when I use Munchen I get close to what I want, but with an expected "bug" in the output. I've tried to come up with a solution, but I have run out of ideas!

Please recognize that the data set here is a **very** simplified look at the actual data in order to be able to post this question. There are about 40 more tags at various levels in the real data so perhaps I'm losing the forest for the trees.

The data contains a set of names and start/end times. Currently if "Jeff" is working from 6-9a his name appears for each half hour of time (6 lines of data). The request is to list "Jeff" as appearing from 6-9a on a single line. I'm using "Jeff" as a test before applying it to the rest of the sheet so I can see what other issues might arise; therefore the test on his name will eventually be removed.

```
<schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Jeff">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="6" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="21600"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="6" minutes="30" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Jeff">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="6" minutes="30" seconds="00" durationinseconds="23400"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="7" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Jeff">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="7" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="25200"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="7" minutes="30" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Jeff">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="7" minutes="30" seconds="00" durationinseconds="27000"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="8" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Jeff">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="8" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="28800"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="8" minutes="30" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Jeff">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="8" minutes="30" seconds="00" durationinseconds="30600"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="9" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Rich">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="9" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="32400"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="12" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Jeff">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="12" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="43200"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="12" minutes="30" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Jeff">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="12" minutes="30" seconds="00" durationinseconds="45000"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="13" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Dan">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="13" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="46800"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="16" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Shane">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="16" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="57600"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="16" minutes="30" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Sean">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="16" minutes="30" seconds="00" durationinseconds="59400"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="17" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Joe">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="17" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="61200"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="17" minutes="30" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Mark">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="17" minutes="30" seconds="00" durationinseconds="63000"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="18" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Kendra">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="18" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="64800"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="20" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Mark">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="20" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="72000"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="20" minutes="30" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Crystal">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="20" minutes="30" seconds="00" durationinseconds="73800"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="22" minutes="30" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Matthew">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="22" minutes="30" seconds="00" durationinseconds="81000"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="23" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Georgia">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="23" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="82800"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="1" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Ben">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="1" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="90000"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="3" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="Ben">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="3" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="97200"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="5" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
<ES_schedules name="McGregor">
    <tx_starttime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="5" minutes="00" seconds="00" durationinseconds="104400"/>
    </tx_starttime>
    <tx_endtime>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION hours="6" minutes="00" seconds="00"/>
    </tx_endtime>
    <tx_txdate>
        <ESP_DATE year="2016" dateindays="42063"/>
    </tx_txdate>
</ES_schedules>
```

When I run this via the Munchean method below my output groups "Jeff" incorrectly. Since he works 6-9a and then 12-1p my output shows Jeff working from 6a-1p.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="groups" match="schedules/ES_schedules" use="concat(tx_date//@dateindays, '_',@name)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="schedules/ES_schedules[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups',concat(tx_date//@dateindays, '_',@name))[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="tx_txdate/ESP_DATE/@dateindays" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@durationinseconds" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:variable name="thisDay" select="tx_txdate/ESP_DATE/@dateindays"/>
        <xsl:variable name="thisGroup" select="@name"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@name = 'Jeff'">
                <xsl:for-each select="/schedules/ES_schedules[tx_txdate/ESP_DATE/@dateindays = $thisDay and @name = 'Jeff']">
                    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@durationinseconds" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@name = 'Jeff'">
                <xsl:for-each select="/schedules/ES_schedules[tx_txdate/ESP_DATE/@dateindays = $thisDay and @name = $thisGroup]">
                    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@durationinseconds" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="tx_endtime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tx_endtime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ESP_TIMEDURATION">
    <!--2011-09-01T00:00:00.000-->
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@hours,'00')"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@minutes,'00')"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@seconds,'00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

> Jeff 06:00:00 - 13:00:00 Rich 09:00:00 - 12:00:00 Dan 13:00:00 -
>   16:00:00 Shane 16:00:00 - 16:30:00 Sean 16:30:00 - 17:00:00 Joe
>   17:00:00 - 17:30:00 Mark 17:30:00 - 18:00:00 Kendra 18:00:00 -
>   20:00:00 Crystal 20:30:00 - 22:30:00 Matthew 22:30:00 - 23:00:00
>   Georgia 23:00:00 - 01:00:00 Ben 01:00:00 - 03:00:00 McGregor 05:00:00
>   - 06:00:00

I know that my problem is that the key is based on the date and name, but I'm not sure how to get XSLT to recognize that I want to group only if the prior time period has the same name.

Comment: It seems like a good job for XSLT 2.0 doing `<xsl:for-each-group select="/schedules/ES_schedules" group-adjacent="concat(tx_date//@dateindays, '_',@name)">...</xsl:for-each-group>`.

Comment: I might be using it wrong since most of our work is in XSLT 1.0, but when I use for-each-group I get "Jeff 06:00:00 - 13:00:00" appearing for both the 6a and the 12p times. So while the name appears proper the start/end time doesn't change. This makes it such that something that is "group aware" needs to be present in the start and end time areas.

Comment: I guess you still have `<xsl:for-each select="/schedules/ES_schedules[tx_txdate/ESP_DATE/@dateindays = $thisDay and @name = 'Jeff']">` which of course should be replaced by `<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">` (or perhaps some min/max computation).

Comment: Thank you! I was not thinking "simple" enough and had tried a much more complex replacement for that for-each. Keep it simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your comments suggest you have an option to use XSLT 2.0 here is a suggestion to replace the Muenchian grouping with `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/schedules/ES_schedules" group-adjacent="concat(tx_date//@dateindays, '_',@name)">
            <xsl:sort select="tx_txdate/ESP_DATE/@dateindays" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@durationinseconds" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

            <xsl:variable name="sorted" as="element(ES_schedules)*">
                <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:sort select="xs:decimal(tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@durationinseconds)"></xsl:sort>
                </xsl:perform-sort>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@name = 'Jeff'">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$sorted[1]/tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@name = 'Jeff'">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$sorted[last()]/tx_endtime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="tx_endtime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ESP_TIMEDURATION">
        <!--2011-09-01T00:00:00.000-->
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@hours,'00')"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@minutes,'00')"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@seconds,'00')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perhaps I miss something. But if I'm right this will only work because there is the Rich entry between the Jeff entries?

Comment: @hr_117, you are right, I was mainly trying to provide a solution for the problem "I'm not sure how to get XSLT to recognize that I want to group only if the prior time period has the same name". Whether that is solving the real problem I am not sure now that I have seen your interpretation and suggested solution of the problem. Let's see what Jason has to say.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the output for Jeff should be the following:

```
Jeff 06:00:00 - 09:00:00
Jeff 12:00:00 - 13:00:00
```

And to stay with XSLT 1.0 you may try:

```
<xsl:key name="groups" match="schedules/ES_schedules" 
               use="concat(tx_date//@dateindays, '_',@name)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="schedules/ES_schedules[generate-id() 
             = generate-id(key('groups',concat(tx_date//@dateindays, '_',@name))[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="tx_txdate/ESP_DATE/@dateindays" 
              data-type="number" 
              order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@durationinseconds" 
              data-type="number" 
              order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:variable name="thisDay" select="tx_txdate/ESP_DATE/@dateindays"/>
    <xsl:variable name="thisGroup" select="@name"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="key('groups',concat(tx_date//@dateindays, '_',@name))">
                <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@durationinseconds" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>     
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ES_schedules">
  <xsl:variable name="thisStart" select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION" />
  <xsl:variable name="thisEnd" select="tx_endtime/ESP_TIMEDURATION" />

  <xsl:if test="not ( key('groups',concat(tx_date//@dateindays, '_',@name))  
        [ tx_endtime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@hours = $thisStart/@hours  and  
          tx_endtime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@minutes = $thisStart/@minutes] )" >
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="not ( key('groups',concat(tx_date//@dateindays, '_',@name))  
        [ tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@hours = $thisEnd/@hours  and  
          tx_starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@minutes = $thisEnd/@minutes] )" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tx_endtime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ESP_TIMEDURATION">
   <!--2011-09-01T00:00:00.000-->
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@hours,'00')"/>
   <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@minutes,'00')"/>
   <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@seconds,'00')"/>
 </xsl:template>
```